# xsd.exe creating invalid constraints in dataset from xsd file

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, xsd.exe

I have a sequence with an allowed minimum length of zero in my xsd.  When I try and load an xml file which doesn't have any elements of the sequence into the DataSet that xsd.exe created I get an exception indicating that my file violated one of the DataSet's constraints.  The xml file validates against the schema so I know it's valid.  Is there anything I can do to make the tool generate a valid dataset?

```
<xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="Numbers" type="xs:double"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Edit:  if I change my schema to this the generated code works properly.  It looks wrong to me though since it appears to be implying that I could have sequence items with nothing in them, which doesn't make any sense.

```
<xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="Numbers" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it is because of the way that xsd.exe handles minOccurs and maxOccurs.  [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c(VS.80).aspx) describes the way that xsd.exe handles minOccurs / maxOccurs.  This section of that article seems to tally with your initial problem:

> A loss of definition precision occurs
>   when Xsd.exe ignores the minOccurs
>   attribute in the case when the
>   maxOccurs attribute value dictates an
>   array binding. A reverse translation
>   from the generated array to a new
>    declaration produces not the
>   original minOccurs value but a value
>   of 0, plus a maxOccurs value of
>   unbounded.

Comment: Thank you.  That does appear to describe my problem.